# Plotting tools for dashboard

Tags: html, plot, gnuplot, dashboard, rgraph

After browsing for a while for available solutions, it is really hard to choose the most appropriate tool for creating dashboard & populating it with plots. I would want to have an html page with multiple plots and tables depicted. I'm thinking to have data input stored in csv files, appropriately formatted.

The requirements are:

- plot coordinates are showing on mouse hover
- ability to show coordinates of points on a plotted line (points in
  scatter plot or bar values for bar chart) 'sticking' to the nearest
  lines on hover, with appropriate handling of multiple lines (show several y values for same x)
- ability to interactively switch plotted data on/off
- easily embeddable into html page, doesn't require additional plugins installed
- a good variety of plot types
- not too slow to load and stable, there could be ~50 plots on one page
  (this is for internal use only, so quickness is not that important)
- does it all with minimal effort

So far I checked out (by no means a final opinion, correct me if I'm wrong):

- **gnuplot+canvas** - looks good, but samples on their page fail to work
  well for me, not always getting mouse clicks right
- **python+matplotlib+mplh5canvas** - feels a bit raw, as I understand
  some of the stuff above I'd need to implement in Python myself
- **RGraph** looks awesome at first glance, not sure if it is good since never heard of 
  it and don't have any experience in js, hard to customize(?)
- some other random stuff which seemed bad enough

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) because of its very advance features and ready-to-use templates (in addition to the things mentioned in the question).

Answer (score 2):

RGraph looks awesome, and is awesome. It's not difficult to use and there are a lot of examples online.
[Rgraph Example page](http://www.rgraph.net/examples/)
They've got 22types of graphs, correct me if I'm wrong, and as I already said, easy to use.
Documentation about possibilities and stuff for each type of graph is also available on the website.

Comment: "RGraph looks awesome, and is awesome" - quite a compliment!

Comment: Yes, but it deserves the compliment. Like I already said, it's really easy to use, the documentation for implementing the graphs is clear. The functions are well explained and there are many things possible to personalize the graphs the way you want.